# Как убрать уведомление WP?

Tags: wordpress

Как убираются такие уведомления в коде?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: написано же : активируйте плагин попросту говоря купите его

Comment: Как убрать эту надпись, это в коде темы походу да? Появилась когда я тему установил

Comment: в коде ..но надо купить его , на стартовой он показывает как работает но ограничено ... купите и надпись пропадёт

Comment: @МаксимЛенский к покупке уведомление не имеет никакого отношения. В нем сказано: рекомендуются следующие плагины: Live Composer... можно нажать на Dismiss, и сообщение исчезнет навсегда

Comment: @KAGGDesign у меня это было когда не активированный плагин .. пришлось взломом заниматься так как покупать его точно не хотел

Comment: @МаксимЛенский вы путаете активацию платного продукта (темы, плагина) и активацию плагина в терминах WP. Любой плагин - неважно, платный или бесплатный - подключается в два этапа: 1) установка, 2) активация. Приведенное в вопросе сообщение предлагает пройти 2 этап с установленным уже плагином Live Composer. Из сообщения невозможно сделать вывод, является ли Live Composer платным. По факту, этот плагин бесплатный, в чем можно убедиться, пройдя по ссылке: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/live-composer-page-builder/

Comment: @kizoso вы неправильно поняли вопрос. В нем нет ничего, что касается платных сервисов. МаксимЛенский сделал неверное предположение о сути вопроса. Я объяснил, в чем он ошибается. И посмотрите мой ответ - где там о платных сервисах?

Comment: Зачем лазить каждый раз в код. если можно просто нажать на крестик закрытия?

Answer (score 3):

Такие сообщения выводятся во время действия 'admin_notices'. Ищите в коде вашей темы нечто такое:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'функция-выводящая-это-сообщение' ) );
```